# Rails app running under Phusion Passenger shows only a white screen

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

I had posted [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740069/when-run-on-phusion-passenger-bundler-cannot-find-the-rails-directory) earlier about deployment with Passenger. That problem turned out to be a permissions issue, and I fixed it by running chmod on the www folder recursively.

Now, I don't get the Phusion error page, but I get a white screen of death. The Rails logs show no error messages, and I cannot figure out what is going down here.

EDIT: These come from the error log...at least I think they do. All error.logs have been gzipped for whatever reason. The status code of the page is 500 Internal Server Error.

```
SQLite3::CantOpenException (unable to open database file):

SQLite3::CantOpenException (unable to open database file):
```

EDIT2: FInally got some error output from the server. :-P

```
[Sat Sep 18 17:49:55 2010] [notice] Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.2-1ubuntu4.2 with Suhosin-Patch Phusion_Passenger/3.0.0.pre2 configured -- resuming normal operations
Rails Error: Unable to access log file. Please ensure that /var/www/rails/releases/20100918182135/log/production.log exists and is chmod 0666. The log level has been raised to WARN and the output directed to STDERR until the problem is fixed.

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: welcomes: SELECT "welcomes".* FROM "welcomes"): app/controllers/welcomes_controller.rb:5:in `index'
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: welcomes: SELECT     "welcomes".* FROM "welcomes"): app/controllers/welcomes_controller.rb:5:in `index'
```

Comment: Please check and post your webserver's (nginx/apache) error.log file. Also check what is really returned. What is the code of HTTP response? Is there any content? Also you might want to check, if there is no index.html in public/ under your Rails root.

Comment: I checked the error log file. You won't believe this, but the log files are being gzipped, and there are 13 of them. I'd never seen this before. The status code of the page is 500 Internal Server Error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error log is probably being gzipped by the log rotation daemon. It's a pretty standard component of most servers.

Anyway, you're getting a white page because, as the error says, there's something wrong with your database file, probably another permission problem. Fix it and it should work.

Comment: I just cleared all the log files and tried hitting the page again to replicate the error. But it didn't generate an error.log message this time. (Thanks for all your help so far, btw.)